# sql hierarchy count

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, hierarchy

I have a sql table named Parentids of ids and their parent's id (where 0 represents no parent) like follows:

```
id | parentid
--------------
1  |   0
2  |   0
3  |   1
4  |   0
5  |   2
6  |   2
7  |   3
8  |   1
```

From this table I need to a sql query to return a table with the number of children for each id that should result in the following:

```
id | childrenCnt
--------------
1  |   2
2  |   2
3  |   1
4  |   0
5  |   0
6  |   0
7  |   0
8  |   0
```

i have the following sql query but it does not seem to work:

```
SELECT id
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN parentid = tid
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS childrenCnt
FROM Parentids
```

Comment: Please tag your question with which DBMS you are using.  You had both MySQL and SQL Server tagged.  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with **group by** on parentId,

Only members with children:

```
select
    parentId,
    COUNT(*)
from Parentids
where
    parentId <> 0
group by
    parentId
```

**EDIT:**

All members, to match exact OP expected result:

```
select
    parentId,
    COUNT(*)
from Parentids
group by
    parentId
order by
    2,1
```

Comment: @trincot Edited. OP got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

One method is using a `left join` and aggregation.  However, a correlated subquery might even work better:

```
select p.id,
       (select count(*)
        from parentids p2
        where p2.parentid = p.id
       ) as childrenCnt
from parentids p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` parentids and then remove the record that id = 0 (first row). So try this code:

```
select parentid as id, count(*) as childrenCnt
from Parentids
where id <> 0
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
SELECT    p.id,
          COUNT(DISTINCT ch.id) AS childrenCnt
FROM      Parentids p
LEFT JOIN Parentids ch ON p.id = ch.parentid
GROUP BY  p.id;
```

It produces the output you specified.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea668/3)